# printwriter problems with my logger

Tags: java, logging, printwriter

I'm making a logger class, and I'm switching my code over from just println statements to doing a printwriter, however, something has gone wrong and I can't figure out what. Could somebody help? I know the problem is somewhere in the Log method, but I don't know what I can do to fix it.

```
 package com.company;

 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 enum MessageLevel {FatalError, LesserError, Warning, Info}

 public class Logger
 {
private static PrintWriter writer;
public boolean Initialize (String logfilename)
{
    try
    {
        writer = new PrintWriter("logfile.log");
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Your file " + logfilename +" is unable to open for write.\n");
    }

    writer.write("Hello World! \n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

   return true;
}

private static void WriteLog (String msg)
{
    writer.write(msg);
}

private static String GetLevelString (MessageLevel level)
{
    switch (level)
    {

        case FatalError:
            return "Fatal Error: ";

        case LesserError:
            return "Lesser Error: ";

        case Warning:
            return "Warning: ";

        case Info:
            return "Info: ";
    }
    return "programmer error: missing level";
}

public static void Log (MessageLevel level, String msg)
{
    writer.write(WriteLog(GetLevelString(level) + msg));
}
```

Comment: What has gone wrong exactly? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Can you please tell us what is wrong? Or what you were expecting instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log method is giving you an error because you're not giving the write method in the PrintWriter the right parameters. That, and you're trying to write twice at once.

```
writer.write(WriteLog(GetLevelString(level) + msg));
```

Your method WriteLog is void, therefore it doesn't return a string to write. And WriteLog already writes what the String you give it, so either use the writer.write() method, or use your WriteLog method (which does the same thing).

```
writer.write(GetLevelString(level) + msg);
```

Or

```
WriteLog(GetLevelString(level) + msg);
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Also, you need to add an extra bracket to complete the class body.